# Select size is not getting refreshed after dynamically adding options

Tags: javascript, typescript, html-select

I have some super simple code which dynamically adds options to a `Select` element on click. (The options are sent from the server)

```
$document.on('click', 'select', function (this: HTMLSelectElement) {
    const slct = $(this);
    const isdict = slct.data<string>('dictionaryctrlr');
    if (!isdict) { return; }
    let querysrch = slct.data<string>('querysrch');
    querysrch = querysrch ? '&' + querysrch : '';
    const postData = slct.closest('.pseudoRec').find(':input').serializeArray();
    const posturl = getActionUrl2(isdict, 'GetSelectOptions', undefined, 'SelectFieldName=' + leftCutTill($(this).data<string>('selectfieldname')!, '.') + querysrch);
    $.ajax({
        url: posturl,
        data: postData,
        success: (data: any[] | undefined) => {
            if (!data) { return; }
            slct.find('option').filter(function (this: HTMLOptionElement) { return this.value && !this.selected; }).remove();
            for (let x of data) {
                var opt = new Option(x.Value, x.Key);
                this.add(opt);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is, that even though the options are getting added, the user doesn't see them in the opened list, the dropdown still shows tiny/empty.

Only when he re-clicks does it open with all options displayed nicely.

Is there a way to add the elements in some sort of "preexpanding" event? or just a way to tell the dropdown to resize itslef? or some other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check that you select correct `select` element?

Comment: can you post full js and html code?

Comment: Yes. It is definitely the correct `select` element. As I can see the options are added. I even get a miniature scrollbar, where I can scroll through the new options. Instead of actually seeing them all open and expanded.

Comment: Also. I added the full code.

Comment: Any Ideas? Anyone? Thanks!